# Java Nullpointer exception while creating array

Tags: java

I am trying to create an `array` of boats, containing `RaceBoat` objects and `SailBoat` objects. Currently I have this:

```
Boat[] boats;

totalBoatCount = args.length;

for (int i = 0 ; i < totalBoatCount ; i++)
    {
       char firstChar = boatNames[i].charAt(0);

        if (Boat.isItRaceBoat(firstChar)) 
        {
           boats[i] = new RaceBoat(boatNames[i]);
        } 
        else 
        {
            boats[i] = new SailBoat(boatNames[i]);
        }
    }
```

every time I create a new SailBoat or RaceBoat, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. How am I supposed to phrase this to create this array?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with *polymorphism*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Boat[] boats;
```

just declares a Boat[] variable. You also need to instantiate it with

```
Boat[] boats = new Boat[args.length];
```

The part of the line before '=' states that boats is an array that contains Boat instances. The part after it actually constructs this empty array object (able to contain args.length number of Boat instances) and assigns it to the boats variable.

Answer (score 2):

The array "boats" is not initialized, which means it is null.

Answer (score 1):

`Boat[] boats` must have to be initialized before you assign 
`boats[i] = new RaceBoat(boatNames[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

`Boat[] boats` must have to be initialized

```
    Boat[] boats = new Boats[args.length];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < boats.length ; i++)
    {
            char firstChar = boatNames[i].charAt(0);

           if (Boat.isItRaceBoat(firstChar)) 
           {
                boats[i] = new RaceBoat(boatNames[i]);
           } 
           else 
           {
                boats[i] = new SailBoat(boatNames[i]);
           }
    }
```